# which one is primary config file for an application that written by WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, configuration, build, app-config

We write an application with WPF. When we build this project, 3 files is generate for us in addition to :

```
> OurApplication.exe
> OurApplication.exe.config
```

their names are:

```
> OurApplication.vshost.exe
> OurApplication.vshost.exe.config
> OurApplication.vshost.exe.manifest
```

first, what are these files? secondly, which one of this config files are primary? If we delete these 3 files, can we running application?

Comment: Project properties -> debug -> uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process". Gone ;=p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> first, what are these files?

The [`vshost.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331(VS.80).aspx) files are hosting executables for use in debugging. They are used to improve debugging performance, enable partial-trust debugging and give you design-time expression evaluation in the Immediate window.

> secondly, which one of this config files are primary?

None. The primary config for your application `OurApplication.exe` should be `OurApplication.exe.config`. If you've added an `App.config` configuration file to your project the build process will automatically generate `OurApplication.exe.config` using this file unless you've changed a build setting.

> If we delete these 3 files, can we running application?

Yes. These are for debugging purposes only; you do not need them to run your application and should not deploy them with your application.

Answer (score 3):

The *.vshost.exe* are files for debugging, see:[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331(VS.80).aspx)

You dot not need them for your application. The one you want is YourApplication.exe.config